# slide show in div in specific size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have div and i add some images to it to slide show but part of image appear not all image,i change the width and height for image but still probleme what is the reasone this is snippt from my code:

```
<link href="./CSS/js-image-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="./js/js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="slider" width=100px height=100px>
            <img src="./images/Health Care 2.jpg" alt="Health" width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; />
            <img src="./images/war.jpg" alt="War"  width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;/>
            <img src="./images/food.jpg" alt="Food" width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; />
            <img src="./images/education-it-hardware-579.jpg" alt="Education" width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;/>
            <img src="./images/sport.jpg" alt="Sport" width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; />
            <img src="/images/technology.jpg" alt="Technology" width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;/>
        </div>
```

this css:

```
/* http://www.menucool.com */

#sliderFrame {position:relative;width:700px;margin: 0 auto;} /*remove the "margin:0 auto;" if you want to align the whole slider to the left side*/

#ribbon {width:111px;height:111px;position:absolute;top:-4px;left:120px;background:url(ribbon.png) no-repeat;z-index:7;}

#slider {
     width: 250px; 
    height: 170px;/* Make it the same size as your images */
    background:#fff url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;/*make the image slider center-aligned */
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999999;
}
#slider img {
    position:absolute;
    border:none;
    display:none;
}

/* the link style (if an image is wrapped in a link) */
#slider a.imgLink {
    z-index:2;
    display:none;position:absolute;
    top:0px;left:0px;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;
    width:100%;height:100%;
}

/* Caption styles */
div.mc-caption-bg, div.mc-caption-bg2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:0;
    left:0px; /*if the caption needs to be aligned from right, specify by right instead of left. i.e. right:20px;*/
    bottom:0px;/*if the caption needs to be aligned from top, specify by top instead of bottom. i.e. top:150px;*/
    z-index:3;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size: 0;
}
div.mc-caption-bg {
    background-color:black;
}
div.mc-caption {
    font: bold 14px/20px Arial;
    color:#EEE;
    z-index:4;
    padding:10px 0;/*Adding a padding-left or padding-right here will make the caption area wider than its background. Sometimes you may need to define its width again here to keep it the same width as its background area (div.mc-caption-bg).*/
    text-align:center;
}
div.mc-caption a {
    color:#FB0;
}
div.mc-caption a:hover {
    color:#DA0;
}


/* ------ built-in navigation bullets wrapper ------*/
div.navBulletsWrapper  {
    top:460px; left:180px; /* Its position is relative to the #slider */
    width:150px;
    background:none;
    padding-left:20px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* each bullet */
div.navBulletsWrapper div 
{
    width:11px; height:11px;
    background:transparent url(bullet.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    float:left;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;cursor:pointer;
    margin-right:11px;/* distance between each bullet*/
    _position:relative;/*IE6 hack*/
}

div.navBulletsWrapper div.active {background-position:0 -11px;}


/* --------- Others ------- */
#slider 
{
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: You can't specify CSS-attributes like that in HTML. Use `style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"`

Comment: I remove it from html but the same

Answer (score 0):

You're syntax is wrong.
It's either:

```
width="100px" height="100px"
```

or

```
style="width:100px; height:100px;"
```

Comment: I made as above but the same

Comment: At `#slider img` try removing `display:none`. If this doesn't work it's probably something with your Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Initially you have to remove both (width and height) as "menucool" scripts smart enough to normalize images, now in the css// he provided you that 
/* Make it the same size as your images */ ,,

because if you follow the js you will find that all the animation calculations depends on the width and height ,,

so try to use images with 100px * 100px without manual css and update #slider css

```
#slider {
     width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;/* Make it the same size as your images */
    background:#fff url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;/*make the image slider center-aligned */
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999999;
}
```

## look this is the orginal html you used

```
<div id="sliderFrame">
<div id="ribbon"></div>
<div id="slider">
<img src="jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-1.jpg" alt="Welcome to Menucool Image Slider" />
<img src="jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-4.jpg" alt="Pure Javascript. No jQuery. No flash." />
<img src="jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-5.jpg" alt="#htmlcaption" />
 </div>
</div>
```